# Show gif from network use UIL

Tags: android, gif, universal-image-loader

Is there any way to show gif photo from network use [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Congratulations, you just won the most non-question of the night award.

Comment: Wash elephant in park using molaasses

Comment: @BrianRoach  It doesn't even contain a statement - just a single imperative.  Brilliant!

Comment: @Simon - I want whatever it is you are drinking, because it's much better than mine. (re: Elephants and molasses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageViewEx](https://github.com/frapontillo/ImageViewEx) can show gif from network.

Comment: This library is now deprecated.